# Php stop a user from viewing an expired page

Tags: php

Consider the following url based on a sporting event happening in the future:
http://www.example.com/file.php?1615=Submit

The 1615 in the url is the eventid. Now after the event has finishedthe page should not be viewable anymore.

Thus my question is how do I stop user from viewing the page if event has expired? Would something like this be my most efficient option using the following logic:

1. Get event id from url assign to var $check
2. Select event_date from events where event_id = $check
3. If(date('Ymd') > event_date) then redirect user

Is there a more efficient way I can tackle this problem?

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: I think that's exactly the way you should go

Comment: Im sorry I dont see how its short on info I was just asking if there is a better way then the logic I am currently following

Comment: the basic principal works, but the method is a different ball of wax.

Comment: plus, your question falls under a few vote to close categories, such as too broad, unclear and primarily opinion-based, and maybe even "why isn't this code working".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a water down version of what I believe you would like to do, change as needed

```
 $id =  $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 
    $id = substr($id,0,4); //here is your event_id
    //query your database
$data = $conn->query('SELECT event_date from events WHERE event_id ="$id"')
    //get date
     foreach($data as $row) {
        $event_date =($row);
        }
$cur_date = date("Ymd");
if($cur_date>$date){
//do what you need to do
}
```

Comment: I was actually looking for a more efficient way since I have the same code more or less....but thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you're proposing should just be a good way to do this as any, what you can do is redirect them to a 404 page if you really want to give the impression that this event doesn't exist anymore. or redirect to the event page but with a big warning that the event has already expired.